# RTClib.h problem

Tags: programming, arduino-nano, library, adafruit

In Library Manager RTClib and DS3231 work somehow with older versions. RTC time can picked only once and then it give bullshit. Using newest versions screen is empty.
In picture first time is right, others no.
Problem occurs, when loading new driver versions.Earlier code  have been working for years. Sure driver problem ....?[image: in image code only picks time]

Comment: so, what is your question?

Comment: More likely a bug in an earlier RTCLib version masked a bug in your code. The two kind of cancelled out. Now the bug (or "feature") has been fixed it's exposed the bug in your code.

Comment: Putting last version 1.14.0 of RTClib do not help. Simple call " DateTime now = rtc.now();  " works only one time; thats my question.

Comment: Thanks for kind help, problem nearly solved: IR remote and DS3231 clock don't live well in nano board, maybe still a bug in drivers.

Comment: @PetriHietala `Putting last version 1.14.0 of RTClib do not help. Simple call " DateTime now = rtc.now(); " works only one time;` is not a question ... it is a description of the observed behavior .... a question is something like `how can I debug the problem?` or `where can I get the source code for the library?` or `what is the color of grass?`